# postgresql convert from one encoding to other

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

I wrote a csv parser on Nodejs to parse csv files and store them on postgres database. The problem I am currently facing is when I try to upload the CSV file from windows. The default windows encoding being WIN1257 I believe, I am getting junk characters in my database.

I am trying to convert existing data in my database using the convert function followed by encode function but not getting the desired output. Here is the example

```
mydb=# create table test1 (var1 text);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=# insert into test1 values ('nk�s');
INSERT 0 1
mydb=# select * from test1;
 var1 
------
 nk�s
(1 row)

mydb=# select encode(convert(cast(var1 as bytea),'WIN1257','UTF8'),'escape') from test1;
           encode            
-----------------------------
 nk\304\274\303\246\302\275s
(1 row)
```

I need a single quote instead of \304\274\303\246\302\275. Any help ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do explicit conversions. What's the server encoding? Show output of `\l mydb` in `psql` or `SHOW server_encoding;`. What `client_encoding` do you use for this csv upload?

Comment: Hi Craig, here is the output of SHOW server_encoding
`postgres=# show server_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
`
Client side encoding can be different depending on platform. User may create a csv file in any of the encoding format. From windows by default if the file is created via excel, it is WIN1257 and on ubuntu it's UTF8.

Comment: Sounds like someone is not setting `client_encoding` to match the actual input data then.

Comment: As of now, I have added a query to replace the junk character with single quote since I am facing the issue with single quote only. But I  am not liking the solution. I can get Operating System info from the client but building a logic around that will not be safe either. I cannot assume that a file coming from windows will be always WIN1257. Will think more on this. Thanks for your help Craig everytime I come up with a postgres related question :-). I really appreciate it!